# Get number from a string after specific character and convert that number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need a help in regex php.
If in a string find number after some character. get that number and replace it with after applying math. Like currency convert.

I applied this regex https://regex101.com/r/KhoaKU/1

> ([^\?]*)AUD (\d*)

regex not correct I want all matched number here only it's matched 40 but there also 20.00, 9.95 etc.. I am trying to get all. and convert them.

```
function simpleConvert($from,$to,$amount)
{
    $content = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a='.$amount.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to);

     $doc = new DOMDocument;
     @$doc->loadHTML($content);
     $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

     $result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="currency_converter_result"]/span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
     return $result;
}

$pattern_new = '/([^\?]*)AUD (\d*)/';
if ( preg_match ($pattern_new, $content) )
{
    $has_matches = preg_match($pattern_new, $content);
    print_r($has_matches);
   echo simpleConvert("AUD","USD",$has_matches);
}
```

Comment: So, the value you need to match is `40`? Is your regex correct?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  No regex not correct I want all matched number here only it's matched 40 but there also 20.00, 9.95 etc.. I am trying to get all. and convert them.

Comment: If you need all, you can use something like `AUD ([\d.]+)`. That will include the dot `.` as well. And you want `preg_match_all()` to get all matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to get all those values and convert them with `simpleConvert`, use a regex for integer/float numbers and after getting the values, pass the array to `array_map`:

```
$pattern_new = '/\bAUD (\d*\.?\d+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern_new, $content, $vals);
print_r(array_map(function ($a) { return simpleConvert("AUD", "USD", $a); }, $vals[1]));
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/UcMqqP).

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `AUD` - a literal char sequence
- - a space
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits.

Note that `$m[1]` passed to the `simpleConvert` function holds the contents of the first (and only) capturing group.

*If you want to change those values inside the input text*, I suggest the same regex in a `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$content = "The following fees and deposits are charged by the property at time of service, check-in, or check-out.\r\n\r\nBreakfast fee: between AUD 9.95 and AUD 20.00 per person (approximately)\r\nFee for in-room wireless Internet: AUD 0.00 per night (rates may vary)\r\nFee for in-room high-speed Internet (wired): AUD 9.95 per night (rates may vary)\r\nFee for high-speed Internet (wired) in public areas: AUD 9.95 per night (rates may vary)\r\nLate check-out fee: AUD 40\r\nRollaway beds are available for an additional fee\r\nOnsite credit card charges are subject to a surcharge\r\nThe above list may not be comprehensive. Fees and deposits may not include tax and are subject to change.";
$pattern_new = '/\bAUD (\d*\.?\d+)/';
$res = preg_replace_callback($pattern_new, function($m) {
    return simpleConvert("AUD","USD",$m[1]);
}, $content);
echo $res;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7Q7WcY)

Comment: I used preg_replace_callback according to your suggestion. It worked for me. Thanks.